# XML has extra content

Tags: layout, blocks, template, xml

for a plugin we generate an XML output which works on several systems without a problem. One system though adds extra content.

In the related controller we do have the following lines:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
$somevars= array('protocol'=>$protocol,'server_name'=> $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('foo/bar.xml.phtml')->setData('somevars',$somevars);
```

As said, this works on several systems but not on every system it seems.
My question now is, what can we do to prevent magento from adding and/or rendering any other content except the content added via the above lines.

I tried unsetBlock, createClock, addBlock, but still seem to have some issues understanding the concept or the correct order.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of extra content? Did you specify anything in layout XML for this controller?

Comment: Basically some div containers likely added by the template or another plugin. The site where this problem occurs is not created or maintained by me.

Still I would like to make sure that our plugin can output the XML at any time without having to care for the template or plugins in a users Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you only render one block and actually do **not** want to use anything from the `default` layout handle. In this case it's better to not load the layout from XML at all and instead only create this single block:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setTemplate('foo/bar.xml.phtml')->setData('somevars',$somevars);

$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
```

But it's still possible that there are extensions which manipulate any response with the `controller_action_postdispatch` event. To prevent this from being fired, you can set a flag:

```
$this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it later today and flag your answer accordingly if this solves the problem for me.